# Angular.js share service data between directives

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm working on my first Angular.js application and I'm a bit confused.
Currently I have two directives that both need the same data to build up the page.
This data is loaded from an external api.

Now currently I have created this `factory`, which looks like:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('dataService', []);
    app.factory('dataService', ['$http', function($http) {
        var links = [];

        return {
            getMenu: function() {
                if(links.length > 0) {
                    return links;
                } else {
                    $http.get('http://localhost/server/api.php?ajax=true&action=getCats').success(function(data) {
                        return data;
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }])
})();
```

But I'm rather confused how to use this service, obviously if there is a `$http` request, the return will never be called with the correct data.

In my directive I would use it like this:

```
(function() {
    // Menu directive
    var app = angular.module('menu', ['dataService']);
    app.directive('menu', ['dataService', function(dataService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/menu/menu.html',
            controller: function() {
                console.log(dataService.getMenu()); // Return 'undefined'
            },
            controllerAs: 'menuCtrl'
        }
    }])
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your service method so that it handles both synchronous and asynchronous scenarios:

```
  getMenu: function() {
                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                if(links.length > 0) {
                   deferred.resolve(links);
                } else {
                    $http.get('http://localhost/server/api.php?ajax=true&action=getCats').success(function(data) {
                   deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                }
           return deferred.promise;
   }
```

Usage:

```
dataService.getMenu().then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work just fine. However, when I use it, am I correct that I should use `var self = this; // In then() promise self.data = data`?

Comment: @woutr_be You could just inject $scope in your directive controller function and say `$scope.data = data`. Tbh I get a bit confused with all that self=this malarkey.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused about how to use $scope, I tried injecting it into my directive controller, but I keep getting an error: `Module '$scope' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.` http://pastebin.com/bDiUfum5

Comment: All the documentation about it is so inconsistent and there are different styles all over the place

Comment: @woutr_be There is no need to inject $scope into the module and directive definition itself, `app.directive('menu', ['$scope',`, remove $scope from there, just inject it to your controller function. Also remove it from here: `angular.module('menu', ['$scope', 'dataService']);`

Comment: That doesn't return an arrow, however if I use `data` in my template there's nothing happening `<li ng-repeat="link in menuCtrl.data">` This is the way I have it now: http://pastebin.com/kLFjXaeE

Comment: Apparently I had to return the $scope

Comment: I see, also don't give the same name as your main module to the directive. call your app `menu` and the directive `menuDctv` or something, just not the same name.